# What does the linux page address '0xdead0000~~' mean?

Tags: linux, kernel, kgdb

I used kgdb to debug linux kernel and print *page.
The result shows some addresses started with '0xdead'

Like, `{lru = {next = 0xdead000000000100, prev = 0xdead000000000122},`

[0xdead pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXNCC.png)

What those pages mean? a NULL page? or something meaningful?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These pointers are [poison](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.9-rc5/source/include/linux/poison.h) constants. They are set to next and previous when a list entry is removed from the list. See [list_del()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6/C/ident/list_del).